# Postgres: Identifying partitions older than N days to drop them

Tags: database, postgresql, database-partitioning

I have a table partitioned by a timestamp field in a postgres database (v 13.11). I create new partitions every day. How do I look for partitions older than N days so I can drop then?

```
CREATE TABLE events
(
    record_id       BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    events          TEXT,
    status          int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    insert_time     bigint DEFAULT date_part('epoch'::text, timezone('utc'::text, now())),
    event_source    varchar(255),
    row_insert_time timestamp not null default current_timestamp
) PARTITION BY RANGE (row_insert_time);


create table IF NOT EXISTS events_2023_12_21 PARTITION OF events FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-21 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-21 23:59:59')
create table IF NOT EXISTS events_2023_12_22 PARTITION OF events FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-22 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-22 23:59:59')
create table IF NOT EXISTS events_2023_12_23 PARTITION OF events FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-23 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-23 23:59:59')
create table IF NOT EXISTS events_2023_12_24 PARTITION OF events FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-24 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-24 23:59:59')
create table IF NOT EXISTS events_2023_12_25 PARTITION OF events FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-25 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-25 23:59:59')
create table IF NOT EXISTS events_2023_12_26 PARTITION OF events FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-26 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-26 23:59:59')
```

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a table for each day. Instead, create use 1 events table but a column for the date, if required.

Comment: @Bohemian not sure I understand. Are you suggesting creating partitions the way I am doing is not best practice?

Comment: creating an entity (view, table, whatever) per day is not a good idea, because clients won't have a consistent model to use. I've never encountered anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a query like

```
SELECT t.oid::regclass
FROM pg_class AS t
   JOIN pg_inherits AS i ON t.oid = i.inhrelid
WHERE (regexp_match(
          pg_get_expr(t.relpartbound, oid),
          '\(''([^'']*)''\)'
       )
      )[1]::timestamp < localtimestamp - INTERVAL '3 days'
   AND i.inhparent = 'events'::regclass
   AND t.relkind = 'r';
```

The way you declare the partitions, there is no partition for a timestamp like `2023-12-21 23:59:59`, because the upper end is always excluded from the range. You should create your partitions like this:

```
... FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-12-21 00:00:00') TO ('2023-12-22 00:00:00')
```

Comment: thanks. WIll make that change. The i.inhparent (in pg_inherts) is a number in my postgres. Hence that query is returning 0 rows. Still trying to figure out.

Comment: `'events'::regclass` is also a number, so that should work.Perhaps there is an error in my `WHERE` condition - do you get results if you omit it?

Comment: for me that is showing a string: events

Comment: Right, but it is still a number (object ID) that just looks like a string :^)